# Experimenters regretting throwing away data?

Tags: physics, experimental-physics, big-list

Modern experiments, especially in fields like particle physics, often collect far more data than they can process and save. Similarly, I can imagine that historical experimenters were limited by how much they could write down.

Experimenters have to carefully consider which data captured by their sensors to save, and which to throw away, roughly dependent on the theory they are testing.

Are there known examples of instances in which it was later noticed that data which was collected, but thrown away, could have been used? Including instances where a new theory might have been able to be tested by historical data that was thrown away?

Comment: My favorite counter example is PMS Blackett's 1925 paper identifying the 14N($\alpha$,p)17O reaction. He looked through 23,000 cloud chamber photographs, identified 415,000 alpha particle tracks, and identified 8 (yes, eight) collisions that could be identified as the nuclear reaction. The experiment was not designed to look specifically for a nuclear reaction, but the data was there to be looked through (well before computer vision algorithms).